# Why does my Qnap NAS TS-431 status light keep flashing?

Tags: qnap

I've got a Qnap TS-431. It's got a flashing red/green status light - so something is wrong and I'm trying to figure out what that is. The fan seems to work if I've just got 1 HDD (but the status remains flashing red/green) and when I added more HDDs, it just keeps rebooting.

Without any HDDs, the fan just runs quietly and the red/green status light keeps flashing.

Can I just replace the fan to fix this issue(s) or are there possibly other issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue with TS-210. After firmware upgrade QNAP went to reboot and after that flashing red and green every 0.5 sec. Tried removing both HDDs and entering firmware recovering mode - all the same: it just flashes red/light and there is no beep on startup. Have not found a solution yet... ((

Answer (score 0):

reboot your QNAP device, and then try to download/upgrade the firmware again. If it's still failed, try to manually download the fireware file from QNAP website, then upload and update it. Should be ok.

This issue usually was caused by fireware file since 4.O.